Why is my linux kernel showing as a "debug kernel"?
I have a fairly standard yocto (nanbield) system running on an intel machine.  I see the following message when I boot:
**********************************************************
**   NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE   **
**                                                      **
** trace_printk() being used. Allocating extra memory.  **
**                                                      **
** This means that this is a DEBUG kernel and it is     **
** unsafe for production use.                           **
**                                                      **
** If you see this message and you are not debugging    **
** the kernel, report this immediately to your vendor!  **
**                                                      **
**   NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE NOTICE   **
**********************************************************

I had previously had yocto debug tweaks enabled, and I was sure that was the problem.  But I removed that line from my yocto config and I'm still seeing this.  What's going on?  Is this normal for a yocto-built kernel?  Or is one of the standard modules doing this?  How can I fix this, as I do intend to use this kernel on production systems.

See here on askubuntu: Probably a third-party driver which calls trace_printk().
